# /var/spool/mail/root file deleted by accident

Tags: linux, email, data-recovery

The `/var/spool/mail/root` file was deleted by accident; I need to recover it.
Is there any link related to this file or how this file got updated which script responsible for it?

Comment: what do you do for backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/var/spool/mail/root` typically contains locally delivered email for the root user. For example,

```
echo hello, world | mail -s 'kandr test' root
```

If you don't have a backup then you have lost your local email for this user account. (If you didn't ever read it then consider it a safe loss.)

Don't try to recreate the file. It will be recreated automatically the next time the root user account receives a message. (You can read such messages with the `mail` or `mailx` command.)